VS Code 1.90 does not show language hint in new editor. Why?
when i used to work on vs code initially , i used to enter ctrl+n and then i used to get blue highlighted text saying file language,file type etc... in which i used to click on that and then used to choose the language i wanted to work on, but now when i pres ctrl+n , it automatically opens as textfile, like now i am not geting to choose the type or lanuage of file i want, so what to do now??? how to bring baack vscode to its normal state and why did this occur? what are the causes??
i tried ctrl+n and was expecting to choose the type of file from the blue-highlighhted letters and choose it
but what i got is i get directly a text file opened when trying ctrl+n, what to do?????????????

It's a known issue with VS Code 1.90. See issue ticket Untitled editor hint is gone #214679. It's fixed by commit 39ae41a, which is scheduled to be in the June 2024 release (v1.91). Also note that the setting to toggle this was originally named workbench.editor.untitled.hint, and has been changed to workbench.editor.empty.hint (it should auto migrate when working properly).
It actually only got partially fixed in 1.91. The hint shows up, but "Select a language" does nothing.
